# Why am i getting a register error when executing this Bukkit plugin code?

Tags: java, class, minecraft, bukkit

Ok, so when i attempt to run my plugin it just throws this error.
http://prntscr.com/8j3d4f
I have tried to fix this by registering the IconMenu class but it won't seem to work.

Main Class Star

```
package me.JukeBoxSensei.RulesStar;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Star extends JavaPlugin implements Listener
{


    Logger log = Bukkit.getLogger();
    MyConfigManager manager;
    MyConfig rulesConfig;

    @Override
    public void onEnable()
    {
        log.info("[RuleStar]Loaded successfully!");
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
        pm.registerEvents(this, new IconMenu());
        rulesConfig = manager.getNewConfig("RuleStar.yml", new String[] {"RuleStar Config File", "Plugin by JukeBoxSensei"});
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable()
    {
        log.severe("[RuleStar]Something broke or we restarted!");

    }


    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) 
    {





        if(sender instanceof Player)
        {
            Player p = (Player) sender;

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("rs") &&  Double.parseDouble(args[0]) <= 5) 
            {

                StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 2; i < args.length; i++)
                {
                    r.append(' ').append(args[i]);

                }
                rulesConfig.set("Rule." + args[0] , r.toString());
                rulesConfig.saveConfig();
            }
            else
            {
                p.sendMessage("Either you did note specify an indencie or it was not in range 0 to 5");
                p.sendMessage("Or your indencie was a string!");

            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    IconMenu menu = new IconMenu("My Fancy Menu", 9, new IconMenu.OptionClickEventHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onOptionClick(IconMenu.OptionClickEvent event) {
            event.getPlayer().sendMessage("You have chosen " + event.getName());
            event.setWillClose(true);
        }
    }, this)
    .setOption(3, new ItemStack(Material.APPLE, 1), "Food", "The food is delicious")
    .setOption(4, new ItemStack(Material.IRON_SWORD, 1), "Weapon", "Weapons are for awesome people")
    .setOption(5, new ItemStack(Material.EMERALD, 1), "Money", "Money brings happiness");

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e)
    {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        if(p.getItemInHand().getItemMeta().getLore().contains(ChatColor.GREEN + "Rule Star"));
        {
            menu.open(p);

        }

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent j)
    {
        Player player = j.getPlayer();
        if(rulesConfig.contains("Players." + player.getUniqueId()) == false)
        {
            rulesConfig.set("Players." + player.getUniqueId(), player.getUniqueId());
            rulesConfig.saveConfig();

        }

    }

}
```

The IconMenu Class

```
package me.JukeBoxSensei.RulesStar;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority;
import org.bukkit.event.HandlerList;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryCloseEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;

public class IconMenu implements Listener {

    private String name;
    private int size;
    private OptionClickEventHandler handler;
    private Plugin plugin;

    private String[] optionNames;
    private ItemStack[] optionIcons;

    public IconMenu(String name, int size, OptionClickEventHandler handler, Plugin plugin) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.plugin = plugin;
        this.optionNames = new String[size];
        this.optionIcons = new ItemStack[size];
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }


    public IconMenu setOption(int position, ItemStack icon, String name, String... info) {
        optionNames[position] = name;
        optionIcons[position] = setItemNameAndLore(icon, name, info);
        return this;
    }

    public void open(Player player) {
        Inventory inventory = Bukkit.createInventory(player, size, name);
        for (int i = 0; i < optionIcons.length; i++) {
            if (optionIcons != null) {
                inventory.setItem(i, optionIcons[i]);
            }
        }
        player.openInventory(inventory);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        HandlerList.unregisterAll(this);
        handler = null;
        plugin = null;
        optionNames = null;
        optionIcons = null;
    }

    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.MONITOR)
    void onInventoryClose(InventoryCloseEvent event) {
        if (event.getInventory().getTitle().equals(name)) {
            destroy();
        }
    }

    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.MONITOR)
    void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
        if (event.getInventory().getTitle().equals(name)) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
            int slot = event.getRawSlot();
            if (slot >= 0 && slot < size && optionNames[slot] != null) {
                Plugin plugin = this.plugin;
                OptionClickEvent e = new OptionClickEvent((Player) event.getWhoClicked(), slot, optionNames[slot]);
                handler.onOptionClick(e);
                if (e.willClose()) {
                    final Player p = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();
                    Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            p.closeInventory();
                        }
                    }, 1);
                }
                if (e.willDestroy()) {
                    destroy();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public interface OptionClickEventHandler {
        public void onOptionClick(OptionClickEvent event);
    }

    public class OptionClickEvent {
        private Player player;
        private int position;
        private String name;
        private boolean close;
        private boolean destroy;

        public OptionClickEvent(Player player, int position, String name) {
            this.player = player;
            this.position = position;
            this.name = name;
            this.close = true;
            this.destroy = false;
        }

        public Player getPlayer() {
            return player;
        }

        public int getPosition() {
            return position;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public boolean willClose() {
            return close;
        }

        public boolean willDestroy() {
            return destroy;
        }

        public void setWillClose(boolean close) {
            this.close = close;
        }

        public void setWillDestroy(boolean destroy) {
            this.destroy = destroy;
        }
    }

    private ItemStack setItemNameAndLore(ItemStack item, String name, String[] lore) {
        ItemMeta im = item.getItemMeta();
        im.setDisplayName(name);
        im.setLore(Arrays.asList(lore));
        item.setItemMeta(im);
        return item;
    }

}
```

I am rather new to coding so this is really puzzling. I'm sure i'm missing something obvious but, i could really use some help. My Mc Version is 1.8.8 and same for the Bukkit server (1.8.8). Any would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seams like it's a problem with plugin registering, rather than code it self. I believe bukkit is for a minecraft game, yes? It seams you didn't do something right to register it.

Comment: You are registering the events for the icon class twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted should cause an error during compilation because of the line `pm.registerEvents(this, new IconMenu());`. Since you defined your own convenience constructor for the IconMenu class, there is no default constructor `new IconMenu()` and you have to provide the required arguments for the parameters that you listed: `IconMenu(String name, int size, OptionClickEventHandler handler, Plugin plugin)`. The order of the arguments for registering a listener should also be the other way around: First the listener, then the plugin.

I'm assuming that you've already fixed this mistake, seeing that you got to the runtime error you linked to. The IllegalPluginAccessException is being thrown because of the last line in the IconMenu constructor: `plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);`. If you remove this line, and keep the `pm.registerEvents(new IconMenu(...), this);` part in your onEnable() method, the plugin should load and be enabled successfully. I can't guarantee however that these fixes will make your IconMenu functionality work seamlessly, all this does is remove the errors.